# Property 'userDetailsService': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Tags: java, spring-security

I always get:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0' while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager' to required type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' for property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager] to required type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService] for property 'userDetailsService': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:138)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

**spring-security.xml**

```
<beans 
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<security:http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/WEB-INF/view/error/access-denied.jsp">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ADMINISTRATOR" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/index" default-target-url="/home" authentication-failure-url="/error" />
</security:http>

<bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.syncbro.clinic.service.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />
<bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
</bean>

<bean id="providerManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <property name="providers">
        <list>
            <ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="providerManager">
        <security:password-encoder hash="sha-256" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

UserDetailsServiceImpl.java

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired private UserDao userDao;
    @Autowired private Assembler assembler;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userDao.findByUserName(username);
        if(user == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("[Login] User : " + username + " not found!");

        return assembler.assembleUser(user);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the problem I think:

```
<security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="providerManager">
```

You passed a `ProviderManager` ref where it looks like a `UserDetailsService` is expected.  (Even if this isn't the place that the mistake has been made, the exception message clearly says that is what has happened ... somewhere.)